# Targgeting DFP ads to Brightcove player

Tags: google-dfp, brightcove

I have a brightcove player,
how to targget a DFP ads to the brightcove player by DFP key and DFP value ?

Comment: This question would be better directed to [Brightcove Support](http://support.brightcove.com/en/contact)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the additional targetting keys the brightcove player automatically adds to every ad call: http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/key-value-pairs-passed-video-cloud

I guess "plid" is the one you are looking for.